# Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu won’t connect to wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, ubuntu

Flashed on Raspberry Pi OS, and I couldn’t connect to the internet by any graphical or terminal means, so I tried Ubuntu but I get the same results. I got this PI less than a year ago and have barely used it until recently, so I don’t think it should have much damage. None of the solutions I’ve found have worked, so if anyone can help that would be great. I keep getting the error “Password or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network”, and I’m 102% sure that the password is correct.

Comment: It doesn't work questions are FUTILE. What did YOU do to set it up? Exactly what OS did you use? If Raspberry Pi OS doesn't using Ubuntu isn't going to make it any easier.

Comment: @Milliways Sorry for not being too detailed, first time posting here of course. I used the Raspberry Pi Imager, on a Raspberry Pi 4, 4GB model. OS was Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 64-bit, and I tried setting up the WiFi in the graphical setup, and in the network settings after setup. Basically the same process with Raspberry Pi OS too. I also tried disabling the MAC filter in my router, but it's already been disabled for other linux related shenanigans.

Comment: any "special" characters in the wifi password? perhaps your keyboard isn't sending the "right" keys - I know (in the past at least) the "default" key mapping is UK - so, there are some surprises with the characters that some keys produce

Comment: @JaromandaX nope, just regular a-z characters and 0-9